# Uploading video to Youtube to a master account

Tags: codeigniter, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I need to have people **sending videos** directly to **my customer's Youtube account**.
My customer doesn't want to have people login with their own Youtube account. This has to be **transparent** for people so they are not forced to have a Youtube account to send videos.
I found several solutions like Youtube Direct lite or the Youtube Widget but this is not exactly what they need as it force them to log to their own account... Same with Youtube API and OAuth2...

Is there any solution with the YouTube Data API v3 even if this is not really "best practice"
?

(I'm using PHP on Codeigniter)
Best regards.

Comment: Ive never done this before, but maybe you could have one of those apps setup on a server running in the background. Once a user uploads a file it gets placed in a directory on the server which the app could be monitoring. This would get around the problem of having to hand out your clients youtube login credentials, however i could not comment on how to do this in the code!

Comment: @micb The only issue I see with that is if it wasn't done 100% correctly (correct permissions, etc...), someone could upload something inappropriate to the folder which would automatically push it to YouTube.  Of course as long as folder permissions on the server was secure and you required users to have a login of some kind, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @kevindeleon I agree, if they was to use this method they would need to make sure that the system was very secure. Ideally the upload folder would be outside of the root of the website, also you would need to have strict access controls for the pages that enable the access to the uploader. I have posted some links in an answer below, there looks to be a way to achieve this within PHP.

Comment: In v3 of the API this is not supported; you cannot have users upload videos to anything other than their own account.

Comment: Thanks @jlmcdonald I'm afraid that my customer will have to ask visitors to log in so...

Answer (score 0):

I've just done a search on Google and found

http://tuts.stackarena.com/2013/03/uploading-videos-to-youtube-from-your-website-in-php/

It may also be worth checking out https://developers.google.com/youtube/ for additional resources, usually you find Google will have a solution for your needs.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks micb, unfortunately I need to use the v3 api and not v2. This makes things more difficult! –

Comment: not a problem, the other option is to take the general ideas from the tutorial and try apply them to the v3 API. I have no idea about what the differences are though, so you would have to work that out for yourself, sorry i can't be more help...